# SQLAlchemy operational error: no such table column user_id when trying to create new DB row

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am getting the below error when trying to add an ingredient on my Account page (which just includes the form AddToPantry - one field, ingredient_name).

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table ingredient has no column named user_id [SQL: 'INSERT INTO ingredient (ingredient_name, user_id) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: ('bread', 1)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Here are my models:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    recipes = db.relationship('Recipe', backref='user', lazy=True)
    pantry_items = db.relationship('Ingredient', backref='user', lazy=True)
    # meal_plans = db.relationship('Meal Plan', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email})"

class Recipe(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    spoonacular_id = db.Column(db.Integer)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Recipe('{self.spoonacular_id}')"

class Ingredient(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ingredient_name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Recipe('{self.ingredient_name}')"
```

And this is my route for the account page, which is where the form is being loaded:

```
@app.route("/account", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def account():
    form = AddToPantry()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ingredient = Ingredient(ingredient_name=form.ingredient_name.data, user=current_user)
        db.session.add(ingredient)
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template('account.html', title='Account', form=form)
```

Comment: I don't use the library but I'm reasonably confident that you've modified the classes and not applied migrations from flask-migrate

Comment: Flask-Migrate really isn't necessary. I don't use it and I just do a db.drop_all() and db.create_all().

Comment: Oki doki. Then how do you explain your error? `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table ingredient has no column named user_id` but the class does.

Comment: I don't know. I've never used flask-migrate before and have never had this problem but I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had old pycache data. Once I deleted this folder, dropped my tables and recreated them the issue was resolved.

Comment: Probably the pycache had no role, but the dropping and recreation of tables added the missing column.

Comment: I had previously tried dropping and recreating the tables and it did nothing so I'm fairly certain it was the pycache.